# ConTEXt doesn't seem to typeset quotation marks correctly

Tags: context-mkiv

ConTEXt doesn't seem to use backticks and apostrophes in the way I'm expecting. I can't find anything in the documentation to suggest how to do this properly, but I would have thought it would be the same as TeX, i.e. a single backtick should be an opening quotation mark and a single apostrophe should be the closing quotation mark --- and doubling these up should give me double quotes.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT for egreg's request for code:

```
\starttext

``How do you `like' those?'' said the horse.

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard font set up in ConTeXt (MkIV) doesn't activate the 'standard' TeX ligatures for quote marks. Instead, the ConTeXt approach is to use logical mark-up here

```
\starttext
\quote{Hello world}
\stoptext
```

Note that the ligatures `--` (en-dash) and `---` (em-dash) *are* activated as these two are generally useful.

Whilst it is possible to load fonts with different ligature set ups, as this approach is a [deliberate decision by the ConTeXt team](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Quotes) I would recommend using the `\quote` macro. (See http://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg25342.html for discussion about ligatures in ConTeXt.)

Comment: See also http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Quotes for more on nested quotes etc.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Indeed: I'm entirely happy with the ConTeXt position here (then again, the rest of the team suspect I'm a ConTeXt mole!). I've edited in the link, as it's probably part of the 'answer proper'.

Comment: @JosephWright thanks for the great and very helpful answer.

Comment: Regarding `--` and `---` Hans recently said “it's about time 
that texies start using the proper unicode symbols instead of these 
funny ligatures” https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/094212.html

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Joseph's answer, the other way to use quotes is to input unicode quotation marks:

```
\starttext
“How do you ‘like’ those?” said the horse.
\stoptext
```

You can set shortcuts in your editor to typeset the quotes quickly. For example, in vim, one can use the digraphs `CTRL-K+"+6` for open double quote and `CTRL-K+"+9` for close double quote and `CTRL-K+'+6` for open single quote and `CTRL-K+'+9` for close single quote

As mentioned by egreg, on Mac you can type `ALT-{` and `ALT-SHIFT-{` for double quotes and `ALT-}` and `ALT-SHIFT-}` for single quotes.

Comment: On my Mac OS X keyboard I can directly type `ALT-{` and `ALT-SHIFT-{` for the double quotes `“` and `”`; or `ALT-}` and `ALT-SHIFT-}` for `‘` and `’`. Works in any editor; perhaps also with `vim`, but I don’t use it. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: They work in vim as well!

Comment: To add to the list, in Linux (Ubuntu at least) you can use `AltGr+V` and `AltGr+B` for double quotes and `AltGr+Shift+V` and `AltGr+Shift+B` for single quotes.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: On linux, the shortcuts definitely depend on the desktop environment (Gnome, KDE, XFCE, ...).

Comment: @Aditya Ooh, that I didn't know, thanks for the clarification :) In this case, my statement would be true for Unity.